# What enclosed geometry amplifies sound the most?

Tags: classical-mechanics, acoustics, geometry

I am going to build a record player. It will read sound electronically but I also want it to be able to project sound mechanically, like a classic record player. So if sound enters a tube, can you know what geometry will amplify the sound the most?

I'm not attached to the original horn design at all, I just like that records can be heard without electronics.

EDIT* To clarify I am asking what the best geometry to amplify a sound is. Is there a better option than a horn? If it is a horn do twists and turns help? At what rate should it open up to best amplify sound?

Comment: Passive geometry doesn't actually amplify sound, it merely achieves a much better matching between the source and the surrounding air. Long exponential horns come pretty close to what  you want, already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a Trumpet loud speaker work?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112466/)

Comment: Two notes: (1) curving or folding the horn (which as another comment says is the best shape) will reduce its performance slightly but make it a lot more practical; and (2) unless you want to play 78s this isn't going to work very well: microgroove records have closely-spaced grooves with very small displacements and were not designed for use without electronic amplification.